# регулярка на поиск букв

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Хочу проверить с помощью регулярок указаны ли в слове **только** буквы. Регулярка `/^[а-яa-z]+$/i`, проверочное слово "Тематический". Подскажите пожалуйста что я упускаю. Методом проб смог установить что совокупность символов привязки к началу и концу строки (^$) дают сбой. Указывая их по отдельности, выражение находит совпадение.

```
<?php
$value = "Тематический";
var_dump(preg_match("/^[а-яa-z]+$/i", $value));
```

Comment: `u` пропускаете

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/rPO2a3/1 - как пример рассмотрите `/(?<![\p{L}\d\w])\p{L}+(?![\p{L}\d\w])/gm`. `\p{L}` - под совпадения попадают заглавные и строчные буквы любого языка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пропустила букву `ё` и флаг `u`: [песочница](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4BLpSwxpzRVwVZB6cKiC1sv7Lmw4WLThR0X2y9svdh4YdeFHRd2KllzlSUWxaeU5hZoFBSlpsfnJpYkZ2go6cdFX9ige7H/4sRE3apYbRX90kwlHQWIeZqa1v//AwA)

```
<?php
$value = "Тематический";
var_dump(preg_match("/^[а-яёa-z]+$/ui", $value));
```

Comment: А где можно поподробнее почитать про этот флаг u и проблему кодировок в регулярках? Я думал проблемы разных языков решаются указанием соответствующих букв a-z для латиницы, а-яё для кириллицы. В Javascript например эта регулярка без всяких доп флагов справляется со своей задачей. И почему если я уберу привязку к началу или концу строк - регулярка найдет что нужно (относительно) без флага u?

Comment: @Paprika для начала и окончания строк, следует добавить флаг `m` - multiline. Флаг `u` - это включение поддержки unicode

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю такой вариант использовать `\p{L}` - поддерживает все языки в любом регистре.

Но так как в вопросе кириллица и латинские алфавиты, то следует установить ограничения:
`\p{Cyrillic}` и `\p{Latin}`, будут использовать именно буквенные наборы символам, принадлежащих этим языкам.
А ввиду того, что слово не может состоять из букв разных языков, то следует разделить их выбор в логическое или, для этого будем использовать незахватываемую группу `(?:...)`:
`(?:\p{Cyrillic}+|\p{Latin}+)`

Для ограничения границ слова для латинского языка используется `\b`, что бы это работало и для кириллицы потребуется установить флаг `u` регулярному выражению

```
/\b(?:\p{Cyrillic}+|\p{Latin}+)\b/u
```

Так же в случае, если в строку будут идти несколько слов, то следует добавить флаг `g` - глобальный поиск

---

Так как `\b` это некий эквивалент позитивного, либо негативного просмотра вперед и назад, ограничения границы слова можно установить самостоятельно

```
(?<![\p{L}\w])...(?![\p{L}\w])
#^^^^^^^^^^^^^_____________________Негативный просмотр назад
#________________^^^^^^^^^^^^^_____Негативный просмотр вперед
```

В просмотре назад проверятся, что перед искомым словом исключаются символы любого языка, цифры и буквы, а так же знак `_` аналогично и в просмотре вперед, только уже после искомого значения

```
(?<![\p{L}\w])(?:\p{Cyrillic}+|\p{Latin}+)(?![\p{L}\w])
```